# Redirect in my custom plugin page in Wordpress

Tags: php, redirect, wordpress

Case: I have a form in the page which enables users to add certain values in a simple text file. Now I want to redirect to the same page after values have been added successfully.

The read/write code all works great, I even put redirection code but this would display warning that `header information is already sent`.

Headers I tried:

```
header("Location: some_url_here_in_same_site");
wp_redirect("some_url_here_in_same_site");
```

My Form code:

```
if(isset($_POST['txtName'])}

    // form validation code here
    if(successful)
        wp_redirect("some_url_here_in_same_site");

}
```

PROBLEM:

- how can we do redirection in wordpress after form submission in our plugin?
- `ob_start` wonb't work, so don't suggest me this either

Comment: cargo-cult programming warning: `"$custom_url"`.

Comment: @MarcB: don't tell me about variable issues, everything else is working, it is just header that is sent already before my header is executed. And any help in this area will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok I managed to do it using Hooks. I did redirection using the code below. Note that the form action is set to `admin-post.php`

```
<form action="admin-post.php" name="frmHardware" id="frmHardware" method="post">
    <!-- form elements -->
    <!-- Essential field for hook -->
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save_hw" />
</form>
```

Then in my plugin's main file, I added the following:

```
add_action('admin_init', 'RAGLD_dashboard_hardware_init' ); // action hook add/remove hardware
```

Where, the function definition is as follows:
Also note that the first argument is derived from `admin_post` which is a reserved word is combined with the `action` hidden field in the form above.

```
function RAGLD_dashboard_hardware_init() {
    // checking for form submission when new hardware is added
    add_action( 'admin_post_save_hw', 'RAGLD_process_hw_form' );
}
```

after the evaluation that form has been submitted in above `add_action`, function `RAGLD_process_hw_form` will be called which is meant to validate form entries and take actions/redirections accordingly.

```
function RAGLD_process_hw_form() {
    if (form_is_validated) {
        wp_redirect( add_query_arg( array('page' => 'ragld/edit-hardware', 'action'=> 'InvalidData'), admin_url() ));
    } else {
        //do something else
    }
}
```

This is the solution I could think of for the time being, you can suggest your answers if you feel they are more effective.